# Optimal method to mmap a file to RAM?

Tags: c++, memory, mmap

I am using `mmap` to read a file and I only recently found out that it is not actually getting it into RAM, but is only creating a virtual address space for it. This will cause any accessing of the data to still use disk which I want to avoid, so I want to read it all into RAM.

I am reading the file via:

```
char* cs_virt;
cs_virt = (char*)mmap(0, nchars, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, finp, offset);
```

and when I loop after this, I see that the virtual memory for this process has, indeed, been blown up. I want to copy this into RAM, though, so I do the following:

```
char* cs_virt;
cs_virt = (char*)mmap(0, nchars, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, finp, offset);
cs = (char*)malloc(nchars*sizeof(char));
for(int ichar = 0; ichar < nchars; ichar++) {
    cs[ichar] = cs_virt[ichar]; 
}
```

Is this the best method? If not, what is a more efficient method to do this? I have this taking place in a function and `cs` is declared outside the function. Once I exit the function, I will retain `cs`, but will `cs_virt` need to be deleting or will it go away on it's own since it is declared locally in the function?

Comment: Why do you want to get this into ram?  Do you want to profile some code with this data, and eliminate the I/O in the timings?  The answer depends on a little bit more context.

Comment: Why use `mmap()` at all, when you don't actually want the benefits it provides (i.e. OS provided buffer/page management of file contents)? Also: `cs_virt` needs an `munmap(cs_cirt, nchars)` at the very least.  Use `memcpy()` (if at all).

Comment: why do you need `mmap()`? if you just need read access to it, just read the whole file in memory using a `stl fstream` and you'll be set.

Comment: It's an extremely large amount of data and the bottleneck is i/o. I am writing this with `mpi` and each process is on a different host which has access to highly parallel shared storage architecture. I want to read once in the most efficient manner possible and thought that `mmap` could help me achieve this as I can just parse the file into `n` chunks and `mmap` that large chunk for processing the data in parallel.

Comment: Reading line by line, for example, would get it into memory, but the data will not be big enough per line to get high throughput from shared storage to the CPU.

Comment: [madvise](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) with an `MADV_WILLNEED` parameter.

Comment: Why don't you just get the file size, allocate a buffer that fits it in, and read the whole file to this buffer? I never understood the point of using `mmap` at all. Besides, if you are using C++, then freakin use it. This code is using none of the possibilities of C++.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux, you may be able to use `MAP_POPULATE`:

> `MAP_POPULATE` (since Linux 2.5.46)
>    Populate  (prefault)  page tables for a mapping.  For a file mapping, this causes read-ahead on the file.  Later
>   accesses to the mapping will not be blocked by page faults. 
>   `MAP_POPULATE` is supported for private mappings
>                     only since Linux 2.6.23.

This may be useful if you have time to spare when you `mmap()` but your later accesses need to be responsive.  Consider also `MAP_LOCKED` if you really need the file to be mapped in and never swapped back out.

Answer (score 0):

MPI and I/O is a murky issue.  [HDF5](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) seems to be the most common library that can help you with that, but it often needs tuning for the particular cluster, which is often impossible for mere users of the cluster.  A colleague of mine had better success with [SIONlib](http://www.fz-juelich.de/ias/jsc/EN/Expertise/Support/Software/SIONlib/_node.html), and was able to get his code working on nearly 1e6 cores on JUGENE with that, so I'd have look at that.

In both cases you will probably need to adapt your file format.  In the case of my colleague it even paid of to write the data in parallel fashion using SIONlib, and to later do e sequential postprocessing to "defragment" the holes left be the parallel access pattern that SIONlib chose.  It might be similar for input.